# The sub-supersolution to solve an PDE

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations, elliptic-equations, variational-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^N$, $N \geq 3$ be a bounded smooth domain. Consider the problem
$$
(P) 
\begin{cases}
-\Delta u = |u|^{p-2}u, \Omega \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,u = 0, \partial \Omega
\end{cases}
$$
where $ 2< p < 2^{*} = \frac{2N}{N-2}$. I'm trying to apply the sub-supersolution method to solve (P). For the supersolution, let $\varphi_1$ the positive eigenfunction associated to the first eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ of $-\Delta$ in $\Omega$. Now define $\overline{u} = \epsilon \varphi_1$. This is a supersolution of $(P)$ for
$$
0< \epsilon < \left(\frac{\lambda_1}{||\varphi_1||_{\infty}^{p-2}} \right)^{\frac{1}{p-2}}.
$$
In fact, noting that $|\varphi_1(x)| \leq ||\varphi_1||_{\infty}$ for all $x \in \Omega$, we have
\begin{align}
\left(\frac{\lambda_1}{||\varphi_1||_{\infty}^{p-2}} \right)^{\frac{1}{p-2}} \leq \left(\frac{\lambda_1}{|\varphi_1(x)|^{p-2}} \right)^{\frac{1}{p-2}}.
\end{align}
So,
\begin{align}
\epsilon & \leq  \left(\frac{\lambda_1}{|\varphi_1(x)|^{p-2}} \right)^{\frac{1}{p-2}} \\
\implies & 0 \leq \lambda_1 - (\epsilon \varphi_1(x))^{p-2} \\
\implies & 0 \leq \epsilon\varphi_1(x)\lambda_1 - (\epsilon \varphi_1(x))^{p-2}\epsilon\varphi_1(x)\\
\implies & 0 \leq \epsilon(-\Delta(\varphi_1)(x))  - (\epsilon \varphi_1(x))^{p-2}\epsilon\varphi_1(x) \\
\implies & 0 \leq (-\Delta(\epsilon \varphi_1)(x))  - (\epsilon \varphi_1(x))^{p-2}\epsilon\varphi_1(x) \\
\implies & 0 \leq -\Delta(\overline{u}) - |\overline{u}|^{p-2}|\overline{u}|.
\end{align}
Therefore,
\begin{cases}
-\Delta \overline{u} \geq  |\overline{u}|^{p-2}\overline{u}, \Omega \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\overline{u} = 0, \partial \Omega
\end{cases}

Now, how can I get a subsolution $\underline{u}$ for $(P)$ such that $\underline{ u} \leq \overline{u}$ ? For the method, it is important that $\underline{u} \geq 0$ and $\underline{u} \not\equiv 0$, because the solution will verify $\underline{u} \leq u \leq \overline{u}$.

Any help is very welcome.